# Set limit to length of Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

The row should be:

- start from latinic letter
- consist from latinic letters, numbers, dot sign `.` and minus sign `-`
- the string should end with an alphanumeric
- min length of row is 1
- max length of row is 20

I've written the following `Regex` pattern:

```
string pattern = @"^[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]{1,18}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}$";
```

and the third, fourth  and fiveth conditions are not satisfied:

```
string s1 = "E";   

// Compare a string against the regular expression
var isOK = new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(s1);
```

Could you tell me the right way to create a Regex pattern?

Comment: You seem to also have a condition that the string should end with an alphanumeric.

Comment: Min length is 3 with your given pattern.  Second expression should have a min of 0.  Not sure what the final expression is all about either.

Comment: Try `string pattern = @"^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,19}(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])$";`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  thanks, but the second condition is not satisfied (consist from latinic letters, numbers, dot sign `.` and minus sign `-`)

Comment: Wy not? It does allow them. Could you clarify with examples?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am sorry for my mistake. It works perfectly:). Could you post your comment as an answer to mark it? Thanks you very much!

Comment: Good, I added my solution as an answer and provided  the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
string pattern = @"^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,19}(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])$";
```

or a bit more enhanced as it will fail quicker with non-matching input and won't allow any trailing newlines ever:

```
string pattern= @"^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,19}\z(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])";
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]` - a letter
- `[A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,19}` - 0 to 19 letters, digits or `.` or `-` symbols
- `(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])` - there should be an alphanumeric before....
- `$` - the end of the string (better replace with `\z` to match the very end of the string)

Comment: A note: you can move the lookbehind after the end of string anchor for better performance with non-matching strings.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not understand how I can move lookbehind after the end of string for better performance. Could you show, please, an example.

Comment: `@"^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,19}\z(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])"`. The `\z` (or `$`) will be checked first, and then the character before it (i.e. before the end of string) will be checked if it is alphanumeric. I added that version to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for so great answer! It is really simple to understand what you've written. Thanks:).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
^[A-Za-z]([-.A-Za-z0-9]{0,18}[A-Za-z0-9])?$
```

It will begin by matching a single alphabetic character, and then optionally a series of up to 18 letters, numbers, periods, or hyphens, terminated by an alphanumeric. You can escape the hyphen in the character class if you wish, but if you don't you should make it the first character in the class so that it isn't interpreted as a range. Making the hyphen the last character in the class works for some implementations.

https://regex101.com/r/fA8lQ4/3